# JavaScript calculate how many pixels 80% of the current screen size is

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate how many pixels in width 80% of the current screen size is.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

        var percentWidth = 0.2;
        var nWidth = (width - percentWidth) / width;   
        nWidth = Math.floor((nWidth * 100));


        console.log(nWidth);
    }, 100);
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

80% of window width:

```
    window.innerWidth * .8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allwidthscreen = screen.width; 

var newwidth = (allwidthscreen * 80) / 100;
```